# Remote debugging of 64 bit process on 32 bit machine

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, intel

I am trying to debug (a simple Hello World application without bug for testing) on a remote intel 64 bit machine from my 32 bit intel notebook.

I run

```
gcc -g -o cexecute cexecute.c
gdbserver localhost:2345 cexecute
```

on the remote machine.

After I forward the notebooks local port `2345` to the same remote port, run `gdb` and type

```
target remote localhost:2345
```

I get:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) target remote localhost:2345
Remote debugging using localhost:2345
warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default i386:x86-64 settings.

warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Remote register badly formatted: T0506:0000000000000000;07:e0dbffffff7f0000;10:c0b6ddf7ff7f0000;thread:p64bc.64bc;core:6;
here: 00000000;07:e0dbffffff7f0000;10:c0b6ddf7ff7f0000;thread:p64bc.64bc;core:6;
```

I am confused since I had this working before. There are similar question for the reverse problem (32 bit application from 64 bit machine) which advise to execute `set architecture`:
[Remote debug error with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697763/remote-debug-error-with-gdb)

I tried this with various arguments and with no success. Also the target platform type `i386:x86-64` seems to be correct. Both machines run ubuntu linux. Since I ran gdb successfully last time I installed version updates on both machines. Where is the flaw?

Comment: What's your version of gdbserver?

Comment: If you do find out the answer, please post, as I'm sure it's helpful to others. My answer was clearly not specific enough.

Comment: If you still have yours post it with the modification `--target=x86_64-*-linux` and I will accept:)

Comment: How about simply connecting to the other machine with ssh and run gdb through that? Seems like a much simpler solution...

Comment: I am using a graphical frontend for gdb and all the infrastructure is on my notebook too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I ran gdb successfully last time I installed version updates on both machines. Where is the flaw?

The flaw must be with your memory: an `i*86-linux-*` version of GDB can not debug an `x86-64` process, you *must* build `gdb` as a cross-debugger (as Mats Petersson already suggested), or get a pre-built one from somewhere.

Something like:

```
./configure --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu \
            --build=i686-linux-gnu CC=gcc AR=ar RANLIB=ranlib
```

should work.